# Problems with Drag and Drop action in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: action, selenium-webdriver

I have written the following code but the element is not being found. The link to the site is http://plugnedit.com/.

I have tried various methods to locate elements on the page to try and drag the object. Its not working. Am getting "Unable to locate element" error.

I am using firefox.

Thanks.

```
        driver.navigate().to("http://plugnedit.com/");
        Actions dragAndDrop = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement itemToDrag = driver.findElement(By.id("p1003upperspan"));

        // drag downwards
        int numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown = 10;
        for (int i=10;i<150;i=i+numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown){
            // this causes a gradual drag of the scroll bar, 10 units at a time
            dragAndDrop.moveToElement(itemToDrag).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0,numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown).release().perform();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the element you are trying to drag and drop is present inside a frame, you need to first switch to the frame containing that element and then perform drag and drop function.

From your code, i was able to figure out that the image you are trying to drag is the image with Coffee cup on it. This image is present in the first frame present in the webpage.

So i have added the following single line of code, before your drag and drop code.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

//Here the frame did not contain any name. 
So i have used index. Here `frame(0)` indicates first frame tag.

It worked ! Use this code.

```
driver.navigate().to("http://plugnedit.com/");

     driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        Actions dragAndDrop = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement itemToDrag = driver.findElement(By.id("p1003upperspan"));

        // drag downwards
        int numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown = 10;
        for (int i=10;i<150;i=i+numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown){
            // this causes a gradual drag of the scroll bar, 10 units at a time
            dragAndDrop.moveToElement(itemToDrag).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0,numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown).release().perform();
        }
```